# Presenting a value based on number or text in cell

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula

I have a list of 4 values in Sheet1 and 4 values in Sheet2.
In Sheet3 I will combine a random selection of these numbers and return the value in a column. (edit: no random selection from Excel, its a part picked from a bucket)

(A fifth column in Sheet3 will be used to do calculations with ValueS1 and ValueS2)

Sheet1

| NumberS1 | ValueS1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 17.10 |
| 2 | 17.20 |
| 3 | 17.12 |
| 4 | 17.15 |

Sheet2

| NumberS2 | ValueS2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 16.10 |
| 2 | 16.20 |
| 3 | 16.12 |
| 4 | 16.15 |

Sheet3

| NumberS1 | NumberS2 | ValueS1 | ValueS2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 17.10 | 16.12 |
| 2 | 2 | 17.20 | 16.20 |
| 4 | 1 | 17.15 | 16.10 |
| 3 | 4 | 17.12 | 16.15 |

What kind of function can give the desired return?

I have looked into examples using "Indirect" but cannot see how they will solve my problem.

Comment: Any lookup function. Look into VLOOKUP or XLOOKUPif your Excel version has that

Comment: Are you doing the "random selection" in column NumberS2 of sheet 3 yourself or do you want Exel to randomly select a value from sheet2/NumberS2 and then find the corresponding value ?

Comment: The value in NumbersS2 is depending on which part has been randomly chosen and then combined with a part with the value NumberS1.

Answer (score 0):

Regular Lookup could do:
`=LOOKUP(A2:A5,Sheet1!A2:A5,Sheet1!B2:B5)` in `Sheet3!C2`
And
`=LOOKUP(B2:B5,Sheet2!A2:A5,Sheet2!B2:B5)` in `Sheet3!D2`

Note that LOOKUP will give the result to the closest match smaller than the search value.

Or VLOOKUP:
`=VLOOKUP(A2:A5,Sheet1!A2:B5,2,0)` / `=VLOOKUP(B2:B5,Sheet2!A2:B5,2,0)`

VLOOKUP will error if the value is not found (the way used above). It uses arguments like this:

`=VLOOKUP(What you want to look up, where you want to look for it, the column number in the range containing the value to return, return an Approximate or Exact match – indicated as 1/TRUE, or 0/FALSE)`

Office 365 has XLOOKUP which combines the logic of the two above and some more:

`=XLOOKUP(A2:A5,Sheet1!A2:A5,Sheet1!B2:B5,"value not found",0)`

XLOOKUP uses the following arguments:

`=XLOOKUP(lookup_value, lookup_array, return_array, [if_not_found], [match_mode], [search_mode])`

Comment: Thanks!
This made it work.

Could you explain what you wrote in the lookup_value field? In my result I did not use a range like `A2:A5` but a reference to a single cell.

Comment: I added an explanation, but it really is regular use of the functions for which Microsoft has explanations documented.

Answer (score 0):

for the randomization: `=ROUNDUP(RAND()*4,0)`
`rand()` gives you a number between 0 and 1, so rand()*4 gives you a number between 0 and 4.

`roundup(x,y)` round up the number x with y digits you want to round the number up to (in our case 0).

for import the right number from sheet 1 or 2: `=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!A1:B2,2,0)`

`A1` - The value you look for in sheet 1 or 2.

`Sheet1!A1:B4` - The array he look for your value **on the firs column**, always on the first column.

`2` - The column you want to import the value from. (because we write an array of tow columns. we can write here only 1 or 2)

`0` - it's an Optionally index (0 or 1). o is if you want an exact match of the return value.